# Bootstrap grid: col-xs-1 Always stacking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 232 and I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
        <link href="less/bootstrap.less" rel="Stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting the columns to display in a single line (my resolution is 1920x1080) but every colum is displyed in a new line. Could you pls tell me if I had missed something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Bootstrap 3.1 language while your source Bootstrap is 2.3.

Just upgrade your Bootstrap to get it working properly. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiperific/hYdWK/1/)

Easiest way to test it is by calling the Bootstrap externally from MaxCDN [here's the instructions.](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Replace your style sheet link with this:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I was using 2.3.2 and a tutorial for the Bs 3.

Comment: @ansurajKhadanga is also right, if you want to stick with Bootstrap 2.3, but I recommend the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap 2.3.2, then you should use it this way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">...</div>
    <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>
```

Please see this link:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

If you have any more queries, reply to this comment else accept this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML mark-up for the columns relates to Bootstrap 3! You either need to use Bootstrap 3 ([here](http://getbootstrap.com/)) or change your HTML mark-up to **.span1** to **.span12** ([see here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem))